# Display: inline removes blocks

Tags: html, css

I've been learning HTML and CSS for around 2 months, but apparently I'm still a neophyte. I'm trying to create somewhat of a header nav bar here, but when ever I set the property `display:inline`, poof ! They disappear. I'm pretty sure this problem is rudimentary but any input you have helps.

```css
div { 
    border-radius: 5px 55px 5px 55px;
}

#Header {
    height: 50px; 
    width: 200px; 
    background-color: #f38630; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    margin-top: 10px; 
    display: inline;
}

.Left {
    height: 300px; 
    width: 150px; 
    background-color: #A7DBD8; 
    float: left; 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.Right {
    height: 300px; 
    width: 450px; 
    background-color: #E0E4CC;
    float: right; 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#Footer {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #69D2E7;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to set the header to display:inline? Headers are usually at the very top of the page and take on the maximum width of the browser. Display:block is probably what you would be looking for honestly. Also, as long as your footer is outside of the header and .left and .right are inside the header, you should not need to use clear:both. Also a reminder that float:left is unnecessary.

Comment: Seeing the general structure of the HTML might help, but as pointed out, `display:inline` is likely not the best option.

Comment: Gwiddle Worker, not sure if you'll see this but thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nutshell, you should not be using `display: inline` for anything that is not intended to be a displayed inside a block of text.

This is a good site for learning layout basics: http://learnlayout.com

If you really want to learn this stuff though, this is the best place I know: https://dash.generalassemb.ly :)

Hope that helps. Let me know if you don’t feel I’ve answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use display : inline -block for divs but apply it to the list items or a tags.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the generation of containing blocks, whether or not your element is inline or block, also the type of positioning. An inline element without content will not show.
Here is the de facto resource for your problem:
[de facto web standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html)

[visual rendering](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html)